# Exclude table cells using php

Tags: php

The code im using as follows

```
ob_start();
?>
<table   cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" rowspan="3"><br /><? echo "لا اله الا الله"; ?></td>
        <td align="center" class="exclude">COL 2 - ROW 1</td>
        <td align="center">COL 3 - ROW 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" rowspan="2">COL 2 - ROW 2 - COLSPAN 2<br />text line<br />text line<br />text line<br />text line</td>
        <td align="center">COL 3 - ROW 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td align="center">COL 3 - ROW 3</td>
    </tr>

</table>
<?
$tbl=ob_get_clean();
```

**i want to exclude or filter some cells from the above code before send it for another processing**

Comment: ... And ? What is the issue you're facing ? What have you tried ?

Comment: as i typed i want to exclude some specific cells the $tbl variable

Comment: @seco Again, what have you tried?  You have not shown any attempt to exclude certain cells.  What is the criteria for excluding the cells?  Why even write the cells in the first place if you are just going to exclude them? Do you really need to exclude them from the HTML source or can they just be hidden via CSS/class treatment?

Comment: i have no idea about excluding ,the only method i know is using jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can then create a style which will hide those cells for you.

```
ob_start();
?>
<style>
.exclude{display:none}
</style>
<table   cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1">
...
```

Comment: i want to exclude those cells have exclude class